# Points in a given volume/Area

Tags: calculus, geometry, volume, area

I have a rectangular prism(3D bounding box) for which i have the point(i.e center of gravity) and the height,width,depth dimensions . Given these parameters, is it possible to find all the points that fall in this volume with respect to center of gravity? If possible, how to do so.

EDIT : I should have put the problem a bit more clear before. 
Actually, there are two different coordinate systems. Lets identify the cooordinates system by names COORD1 and COORD2. The bounding box is in COORD1 system. Given any point(x,y,z) coordinates with respect to COORD2, i should find out if that point lies in this bounding box. I can get the upper and lower bounds of the bounding box using its dimensions,but that doesn't help to compare with point coordinates...because both of them are in different coordinate systems. The only value i have in bounding box is a point (center of gravity) which is with respect to COORD2. So, i am trying to find out a possibility where this point can help me convert the upper and lower bounds of this bounding box into COORD2.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What do you mean by finding all the points that fall in this volume with respect to center of gravity? What are these points?

Comment: I have edited the question . Hopefully it makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

Let's call $O$ the center of gravity of your rectangular prism or depth $D$, width $W$ and height $H$.

Let's call $M(x,y,z)$ any point of the space.

We choose the $x$, $y$ and $z$ axis so that $O=(0,0,0)$ and the axis falls with the prism sides.

You have the equation of all points of the prism:

$|x| \leq \dfrac W2$

$|y| \leq \dfrac D2$

$|z| \leq \dfrac H2$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i think i did not ask the question in a proper way earlier. I have edited the question  now.  Please check.